# C# Interpolating small array into larger array

Tags: c#, .net

I have two arrays of doubles X and Y of same size (any size is possible).
The difference between x-points is always stable. For example X[1]-X[0] = X[2]-X[1]...
These two arrays together form a curve (say C1) of (x[i],y[i]) points.

I have another another fixed curve C2 shown in the figure:
x-limit , y-limit
(0) ,(-5)
(1e9) ,(-5)
(2e9) ,(-6.5)
(3e9)  ,(-9.2)
(6e9)   ,(-16.5)
(12e9)  ,(-29)

[image: Limits]

I want to be able to check if C1 hits or crosses under C2 but I can't do that due to the difference in size.

What I thought of is **interpolating the arrays of C2 of size 6 into arrays of size equal to the size of the arrays of C1**

This way I would have two Y-arrays of same size (one from C1 and one from C2) and I can check for the difference. (If negative then it is below the limit)

My question is what can I use to interpolate the small array into a larger one keeping into consideration the difference between y-points, and is there any other way I could use to check is my initial arrays exceed the limit.

If there anything I could add that is not clear let me know and thank you.

Comment: Some example data would really help make this question a lot more concrete and clear. Currently the only thing I can picture is a couple of 2000-element arrays (of doubles? `Point`s?) and some kind of array of tuples for the limits? Any code you have already is always good to post.

Comment: What do you mean by limit? A limit for a point in a 2d space would be an area. How does this list of limit points work as limit?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I edited my question. A point consists of x from x-array and a y from y-array.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The thing is that when plotting a curve in terms of x-array and y-array, it should not cross the above curve

Comment: @HasanH so instead of having an object `Point` or `Point2D` that have both `X` and `Y` as a property you have 2 array of same length where the same index in both array are defining a specific point is that it ?

Comment: @Franck Exactly

Comment: You question isn't clear as is. the real question is "maybe" something like "How to compare a graph with a baseline graph and check if it's crosses or not". Right now your question is closed as being not clear enough. You need to modify your question in order to clarify every aspect so there is no doubt on your intentions and your question will get reopened and you will get an answer. You don't need over complicate either just mention what you have, what you are trying to do, what you tried, what result you are looking for etc.

Comment: @Franck I am looking for both questions. If it is possible from interpolation and if there is any other way

Comment: @Franck I tried to summarize the question in a different and more clear way

Comment: @HasanH Much clearer and reopened. Think of it this way. Between each point of your `C1` graph there is a line. Each line is and f(x) simple graph. For each point in your `C2` you are trying to find the first point in `C1` where `C1.X` is smaller than `C2.X` and the point where `C1.x` is greater than `C2.X` then from the 2 points of  `C1` you have a line and all you have to check is where `C2.X` lands on `C1` and if the `Y` found is higher or lower than the point your are testing

Comment: Assuming that the x-axis is horizontal and the y-axis vertical, it seems strange that the difference between y-points is a constant. Usually x-points are given (and can be equidistant) and the y-points contain a measurement. Have you inverted the two axis?

Comment: each array forms a line consisting of line segments.  each line segment consists of 2 points. A line overlaps if any line segment overlaps.  So shouldn't think require only testing the various segments against each other?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes You are right I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing interpolated points, I would calculate and use them on the fly.

Assuming that the points to be compared are sorted in ascending order, I would proceed as follows:

```
double limitX1 = limitX[0];
double limitY1 = limitY[0];

// Create fake point to the left
double limitX0 = -2;
double limitY0 = limitY1;

double f = 0.0;

int actualLimitIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++) {
    double x = x[i];
    double y = y[i];

    // Get current limit section
    while (x > limitX1) {
        actualLimitIndex++;
        limitX0 = limitX1;
        limitY0 = limitY1;
        limitX1 = limitX[actualLimitIndex];
        limitY1 = limitY[actualLimitIndex];
        f = (limitY1 - limitY0) / (limitX1 - limitX0);
    }

    // Interpolate limit
    limitY = limitY0 + (x - limitX0) * f;

    // Do whatever you have to do here.
    if (y > limitY) {
        // We are above limit
    } else {
        // We are at or below limit
    }
}
```

This also assumes that no x-value is below the minimum or above the maximum x-limit. Add additional checks if this can be the case.

This uses a linear interpolation. See: [Linear interpolation (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).